# resolveLocalFileSytemURL returning FileError {code:5}?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working on a React project and I am using the Cordova plug-in for the first time. I have it taking pictures correctly but now I want to store them locally on the device using persistent storage. I found pretty good documentation but for some reason cannot get this code to work. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it!

**Here is my function:**

```js
takePicture() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(
        imageData => {
            this.setState({image: imageData});

            let path = 'filesystem:' + imageData;

            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
                path,
                (entry) => {
                    window.requestFileSystem(
                        LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,
                        50 * 1024 * 1024,
                        (fileSys) => {
                            //The folder is created if doesn't exist
                            fileSys.root.getDirectory(
                                'Observation Photos',
                                {create:true, exclusive: false},
                                directory => {
                                    let d = new Date(),
                                        n = d.getTime(),
                                        filename = n + '.jpg';
                                    entry.moveTo(directory, filename, (entry) => {
                                        Photos.insert(entry);
                                    }, handleError);
                                },
                                handleError
                            );
                        },
                        handleError
                    );
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
        }, message => {
            console.log(message);
        }
    );
}
```

**Here is an example of the paths I am passing in:**

```html
filesystem:file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.id1b9kkvri4mj2dnqkf9p/cache/1470171102308.jpg
```

**Returns this in the inspector:**

```html
FileError {code: 5}
```

Comment: Error code 5 means encoding error. So it could be a possible problem with setting mime type. But i did not acheive success while trying to access any files in Android data dir. So i tried using external data directory. For working sample of saving files, check this out - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations

Answer (score 0):

value of Path should be `Android/data/com.id1b9kkvri4mj2dnqkf9p/cache/1470171102308.jpg`;

so it needs a small change:

```
let path = imageData.replace("file:///storage/emulated/0/","");
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I tried it and am still getting the same error. Any other ideas @Tuhin?

Comment: HI Davina please do a check, go to device file storage and check in the folder Android/data/com.id1b9kkvri4mj2dnqkf9p/cache search for 1470171102308.jpg file available or not.